# How to create (Async)EventBus with ImmediateDispatcher?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to create an `AsyncEventBus`, with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I noticed that `AsyncEventBus` is hardcoded to always use a `LegacyAsyncDispatcher`. The javadoc of `Dispatcher.legacyAsync()` states:

> For async dispatch, an immediate dispatcher should generally be preferable.

But I can't find any way of actually creating an `AsyncEventBus` with `Dispatcher.immediate()`. And then `EventBus` is hardcoded to use `Dispatcher.perThreadDispatchQueue()`.

How does one create an `ImmediateDispatcher` and wire it into an `EventBus`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reading too much into the source of this package. Notice that [`Dispatcher` is a package-private class](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fd919e5/guava/src/com/google/common/eventbus/Dispatcher.java#L34), so *you* can't create (or even reference) an instance of any type of `Dispatcher`. The docs on `Dispatcher.legacyAsync()` are therefore intended for other library maintainers, not for users of the `eventbus` package.

In other words, just use `AsyncEventBus` and pass in the executor you want it to use. Maybe one day the maintainers will change `AsyncEventBus`'s implementation to not use `legacyAsync()`, but that shouldn't have any impact on you, the user.